# sqlite3 parameters of unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to make a simple web budget app with a SQL database but I keep getting ValueError: parameters are of an unsupported type

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

def index():
    return (render_template('index.html'))

@app.route("/start", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def start():
    import sqlite3
    import pandas as pd
    if request.method == 'POST':
        connection = sqlite3.connect('transactions.db')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        amount = request.form.get('amount')
        description = request.form.get('description')
        category = request.form.get('category')

        print(amount, description, category)
        cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO transactions (amount, description, category)
                            VALUES ({amount}, '{description}', '{category}')""", connection)

        cursor.close()
        connection.commit()

        table = pd.read_sql("""SELECT * FROM transactions """, connection)
        return(render_template('start.html'), value1 == table)

    else:
        return(render_template('start.html'))
```

here is the SQL database

```
'-- SQLite
CREATE TABLE transactions (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    amount REAL,
    description TEXT,
    category TEXT

);
```

The inputs I used were
10.50, 'Dog Food', and 'Misc.'

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution, do not pass `connection` and use SQL placeholder binding (with `?`) rather than string formatting.

```py
cursor.execute(f"""
    INSERT INTO transactions (amount, description, category)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)
""", (amount, description, category))
```

---

Longer explanation with your original code:

```py
cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO transactions (amount, description, category)
                            VALUES ({amount}, '{description}', '{category}')""", connection)
```

Your origin code is passing the `connection` as an argument to `cursor.execute`, and connection is a `sqlite3` instance, which is unsupported as the supported argument for `cursor.execute` is either a sequence or `dict` for parameter substitution in your query.

Also see the actual definition of the argument, and why my solution code uses `?` instead of doing string substitution:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute

  ```
  execute(sql, parameters=(), /)

  Execute SQL statement sql. Bind values to the statement
  using placeholders that map to the sequence or dict parameters.
  ```
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-placeholders

  > SQL operations usually need to use values from Python variables. However, beware of using Python’s string operations to assemble queries, as they are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (see the xkcd webcomic for a humorous example of what can go wrong):

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry for the late response.